# NSButton Toggle : OnClick title get removed on OSX 10.11

Tags: cocoa, osx-elcapitan, nsbutton, xcode8

I am using a Toggle button in XIB,

in **AwakeFromNib** :I set title and BG image of the button.
Code works very well till **OSX 10.10.5 and below** but on **higher versions** when I click on button the **text gets removed**.

**Set attributed Title**

```
    [self.deleteButton setWantsLayer:YES];
    self.deleteButton.layer.backgroundColor = [self setButtonBGColor];
    [self setButtonTitleFor:self.deleteButton
                   toString:@"Delete"];
    [self.deleteButton setLayerContentsRedrawPolicy:NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay];



- (void)setButtonTitleFor:(NSButton*)button toString:(NSString*)title
{
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [self getAttributedStringForString:title];
    [button setAttributedTitle:attrString];
}
```

[image]
[image]

Any idea hat should be done.

[image]

Comment: Can anybody provide some help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally got it right

Subclassing NSButtonCell helped me out

**RPButtonTextTopCell.h**

@interface RPButtonTextTopCell : NSButtonCell

@end

**RPButtonTextTopCell.m**

@implementation RPButtonTextTopCell

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    return [super initWithCoder:decoder];
}

-(id) initTextCell:(NSString *)string
{
    return [super initTextCell:string];
}

-(NSRect)titleRectForBounds:(NSRect)theRect
{
    NSRect titleFrame = [super titleRectForBounds:theRect];
    NSSize titleSize = [[self attributedStringValue] size];

    titleFrame.origin.y = (theRect.origin.y - (theRect.size.height-titleSize.height)*0.5) + 5;

    return titleFrame;
}
```

@end

**Utilizing This Custom Class**

```
RPButtonTextTopCell *deleteCell = [[RPButtonTextTopCell alloc] init];
deleteCell.backgroundColor      = [self setNSButtonBGColor];

[self.deleteButton setCell:deleteCell];
[self setButtonTitleFor:self.deleteButton
               toString:@"Delete"];
[self.deleteButton setAction:@selector(deleteButtonClicked:)];
[self.deleteButton setTarget:self];
```

and its solved....